# How to make text grow to the left in a span?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a span containing a number that will increment as time passes. However, I would like it to expand to the left, instead of the right as it gain another digit (i.e. from 9 to 10). How can I do that within a span?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need i.e. `text-align:right` or `float:right` etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the CSS **direction** attribute, together with a difined width and display block:

```css
span { 
        width: 300px;
        display: block;
        direction: rtl;
        background-color: #ff0000;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<span> RIGHT TO LEFT</span>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Works like a charm!

Comment: You're welcome. could you please mark it as the answer?